# Windows store app - jQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to import jQuery into blank javascript app, but keep getting same error:   `JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined`. I don know the reason for this.

My whole procedure:

1. Create new Blank app project
2. Add existing item jquery-1.8.2-win8-1.0 in js folder
3. Drag and drop added item into default.html head
4. Add some jquery code in default.js

and now, i'm getting this error: `JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined`.
But if I delete added jQuery code(didn't notice before) it throw's me another error:`JavaScript critical error at line 4, column 1 in ms-appx://8cce31f0-7793-41f7-875e-c41dd9ade2c7/js/jquery-1.8.2-win8-1.0.js`.

I'm trying to get jquery to work for last several hours, but without success.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jquery</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!-- jquery references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2-win8-1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery code:

```
$("*").on("click", function () { });
```

Error's:

[image: 1. error]
 [image: 2. error]

Video:
[Error - jQuery](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsi7q419g-w&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: `<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>` the double slash is used to replace http or https. If **Microsoft.WinJS.1.0** is a folder use a simple slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thank you for [the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsi7q419g-w&feature=youtu.be) - this would have been nearly impossible to solve without it.

I noticed your jQuery file was 2.0mb; this didn't look right. And then the error message took us into its contents to point out a syntax error, where we saw a slew of HTML tags — you appear to have downloaded from the [GitHub viewer page](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-win8/blob/master/jquery-1.8.2-win8-1.0.js), rather than from the source file itself. You should instead download [the RAW file](https://raw.github.com/appendto/jquery-win8/master/jquery-1.8.2-win8-1.0.js).

Please note also that this is an older version of jQuery, and not a fully-supported version. I am the primary developer behind the appendTo repo, and am excited to announce that jQuery 2.0 ([pre-release builds available](http://jquery.com/download/)) should work really well on its own in a Windows Store App.

I wrote about this recently over on nettuts: [Building Windows Store Applications With jQuery 2.0](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-windows-store-applications-with-jquery-2-0/)

Comment: Yes, I downloaded it from GitHub, that's true. I use now the latest version of jQuery and it work's realy nice. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2-win8-1.0.js"></script>
```

after:

```
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This error is probably because you're not include jQuery library before writting jQuery code and make sure the path to your file is correct

Comment: I've tryed, but still the same result :/

Comment: @Klemzy check all your path, I suspect that something wrong with your loading file

Comment: in default.js are all ok. I think. and beside, only what i did is drag jquery...so visual studio generates path

Comment: look at the end of the question. i add video

Answer (score 0):

Try rearranging the scripts you added. Include jQuery js file before your default.js file. Something like this:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2-win8-1.0.js"></script>
<script src="/js/default.js"></script>
```

Default.js tries to use jQuery which is not yet added. So rearranging might help.

Comment: try to check out if the file jquery-1.8.2-win8-1.0.js is getting loaded or not.

Comment: I think it is loaded, becouse otherwise it will be no seccond error(syntax error inside jquery)

Comment: If you could confirm this. You can use any built in developer's tool of any browser to confirm this.

Comment: look at the end of the question. i add video

Comment: can't help. youtube is blocked here. :)

Comment: hmmm. though the video was unclear, still got what you were trying to say. If you notice the path of both the script files, one is starting with /js, while the other with js, could it be the problem? Try adding a forward slash '/' before js in the jquery src.

Comment: I tryed before, but the same result. And now i import older version of jQuery(1.4.4) and it works perfectly.

Comment: And another think if I may ask...if u work with credentialPicker before...does it takes longer to appear in js than c#? because i have both examples and the one in c# is a lot faster

Comment: nah... i haven't yet worked with it before. But if in future i intend to work with it, will keep your advice in consideration. ;)